# Two different JSON keys in the same shuffle in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, shuffle

The correct answer for the questions is always "shSik1" but I aim for this to be complex In JSON sorting.

For example;

```
foreach ($examQuestion as $eq) {
  {
   'question' => $eq->questionContent,
   'choices' => array($eq->shSik1, $eq->shSik2, $eq->shSik3, $eq->shSik4, $eq->shSik5),
   'correctAnswer' => 1
  }
}
```

In the example above, the correct answer to the question is number one (`shSik1`).

Is it possible that the correct answer is complex in the 'Array' in `choices` and the place of the key 'correctAnswer' in this sorting can be determined? (Can it be `'correctAnswer': 3` when it print to `3` place in Array?)

What have I done?

I used "[shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.shuffle.php)" and the correct answer is in complex sequences in Array, but 'correctAnswer' always gives an error. So, I could not run `choice` and correctAnswer` together.

How can I do that?

Comment: That's not valid PHP, but what about `'correctAnswer' => $eq->shSik1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_search()` to get the index of an array element.

```
shuffle($choices);
$correct_answer = array_search($eq->shSik1, $choices) + 1;
```

Comment: Dear @Barmar, thank you for your help, it's work but how to change the array key to start from `1` instead of `0`? Because some `correctAnswers` have `0`

Comment: Add `+ 1` to the result, obviously.

Comment: **Thank you so much** @Barmar